# MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: web3js, truffle, blockchain, metamask, dapps

**I am getting this error when i trying to use metamask on my local for a simple transaction from one account(say A) to another (say B).**

> code: -32603
>   data: {originalError: {…}}
>   message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."
>   stack: "Error: WalletMiddleware - Invalid "from" address.↵    at h (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.js:1:1226252)↵    at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.js:1:1224243"
>   **proto**: Object

[image: Screenshot for the error]

**Solutions I tried on my own(which didn't work ofc):**
1. `Downgrading my web3.js to beta 33,35 and 37 release. Currently, I am using 1.2.0 version.`
2. `Changing my metamask to mainnet and then back to local test net, which I am running on port:9545`

**Below is my smart contract:**

```
contract ApprovalContract {
    address payable public sender;
    address payable public receiver;
    address public constant approver = <some account address>;

    function deposit (address payable _receiver) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
    }

}
```

**And below is my custom js (using web3.js)**

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:9545");

var contractAddress = <contractAddress>;

var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress); 

$('#contract-form').submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var fromAddress = $('#fromAddress').val();
  var toAddress = $('#toAddress').val();
  var amount = $('#amount').val();

  ApprovalContract.methods.deposit(toAddress).send({"from": fromAddress, "value": web3.utils.toWei(amount,'ether')},
    function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
          $('#deposit-result').html('Error: ' + error);
      } else {
        $('#deposit-result').html('Success TX: <b>' + result + '</b>');
      }
    });
});
```

**The flow is going into the last function and displaying the error as below:**

```
error: Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "originalError": {}
}
```

**Expectation**: Since my account A, is the account[0] of Metamask where is logging in to, I am expecting the Metamask pop up to show to confirm the transaction but instead I am getting this "Internal JSON RPC errror."

Any ideas ???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ethereum.enable()** did the trick for me.

My solution:
1. Added:
`window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
try {
           await ethereum.enable();
       } catch (error) {}
});`

2. Updated the gas value:
   `ApprovalContract.methods.deposit(toAddress).send({"from": fromAddress, gas: 1000000, "value": web3.utils.toWei(amount,'ether')}`
3. Changed Metamask network to mainnet, and then back to Local test net, and then reset the account.

For details, check out: [link](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8)

Answer (score 2):

Try to regenerate the JSON file by deleting the old JSON file and re-compiling .sol file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Pranav correctly indicates that there seems to be an issue with garbage collection and disposal.  The simplest method to solve the issue for me was to create a new browser environment:

1. Close every open tab on every window in current browser;
2. Restart browser;
3. Close any tabs which open up;
4. Restart browser (skip if no tabs open in `step 3`;
5. Open `Metamask` and type password (indicates last session closed properly);
6. Select a `Test Network`, `localhost:8545` or `Custom RPC` (don't do this on Main Network for testing, because you will spend real ether).

Answer (score 0):

While debugging I noticed the message: "eth-json-rpc-errors@2.0.2: Package renamed: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-rpc-errors"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-rpc-errors%22)

So the error got solved running `npm install --save eth-rpc-errors`

Note that I also answered in [Metamask transaction confirmed but "Internal JSON RPC error"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/66330/65044)